# Edit (Update) Specific value in MongoDB Document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**I Want to update Only the value of** `payStatus`

```
 data : {
       "profile": {
            "guestName": "Hussein Khalil",
            "mobile": "01223550119",
            "email": "husseinkhalil33@gmail.com"
        },
        "hotelRoomingList": {
            "child": {
                "childAges": [
                    2,
                    4
                ],
                "childNo": 2
            },
            "hotelStatus": "Not Confirmed",
            "roomsNo": 3,
            "adultsNo": 2,
            "travelAgent": "Nilsen",
            "hotelConfNo": "G1B412",
            "roomingNotes": "Some rooming Notes",
            "roomingList": {
                "_id": "604b79ecb102efdea80a0698",
                "roomingName": "Pyramids",
                "roomingDescription": "this is Pyramids travels",
                "revenueMonth": "jul",
                "startedDate": "2021-03-12T14:25:48.830Z",
                "__v": 0,
                "id": "604b79ecb102efdea80a0698"
            },
            "hotel": {
                "_id": "604d511964927d1759884e36",
                "hotelName": "Concorde Front",
                "__v": 0,
                "id": "604d511964927d1759884e36"
            },
            "roomType": {
                "_id": "604d516564927d1759884e37",
                "roomType": "double",
                "__v": 0,
                "id": "604d516564927d1759884e37"
            },
            "mealPlane": {
                "_id": "604aa5a7246f847df848c796",
                "mealPlane": "SAL",
                "__v": 0,
                "id": "604aa5a7246f847df848c796"
            },
            "nights": 8,
            "arrivalDate": "2021-03-27T22:00:00.000Z",
            "departureDate": "2021-04-04T22:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "customerAccount": {
            "payStatus": "not-gura-not-sure",
            "fullPay": 3000,
            "hotelCost": 2050,
            "transportCost": 150,
            "otherCost": 50,
            "paid": 1250,
            "optionDate": "2021-04-05T22:00:00.000Z",
            "customerNotes": "some customerNotes",
            "restOfPay": 1750,
            "profit": 750
        },
        "transportation": {
            "transport": {
                "_id": "604b61b6aad5fab0f3c0d40d",
                "transportType": "Bus",
                "__v": 0,
                "id": "604b61b6aad5fab0f3c0d40d"
            },
            "tripDate": "2021-03-27T22:00:00.000Z",
            "noOfSets": 7,
            "transportNotes": "some transportNotes"
        },
        "bookingStatus": "active",
        "_id": "605dc47ed2ed656bce892182",
        "salesPerson": "noor smay",
        "marketSegment": {
            "_id": "604b60796d049aafef1d3b0a",
            "marketSegment": "Faceboook",
            "__v": 0,
            "id": "604b60796d049aafef1d3b0a"
        },
        "enteredBy": {
            "role": "admin",
            "_id": "604d1b9767fa82ccffc29acc",
            "isAdmin": false,
            "name": "ahmed magdy",
            "email": "ahmedmagdy@test.com",
            "password": "$2a$10$eoYyVF1TTTPQ7pWcCDLVQuvalw8g82yvzzmgD7fvQDH8mCZ4QE30S",
            "createdAt": "2021-03-13T20:07:51.428Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-03-13T20:07:51.428Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "resDate": "2021-03-26T11:24:46.644Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "id": "605dc47ed2ed656bce892182"
    }
```

Comment: I have fixed and simplified quite a bit from the question. However, I couldn't suggest any edits because it says suggested edit queue is full. There has to be 500 edits to fill up that queue so I am wondering if Ahmed is simply ignoring edit suggestions to make this into a nice SO question. More on edit queue: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345157/3554534 for Ahmed to make his own edits: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What I would suggest to @Ahmed is to remove any unnecessary data from your document above, we don't need to know about all the details of your data to suggest the answer below. So you can remove the data for **profile, hotelRoomingList, customerAccount, transportation, marketSegment, enteredBy, resDate, __v, bookingStatus, _id, salesPerson** You can also ask a question at the title to make it more precise what you are actually asking for. Please also show what you tried so people have a general understanding where you are coming to this question from.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/

`updateOne` to update 1 record

`updateMany` for multiple records

```
await db.collection('inventory').updateOne({  }, // query
  {
    $set: { 'customerAccount.payStatus': 'New Value' } // update value
  }
);
```

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/iO4I4zVRnOP

Mongo query

```
db.collection.update({},{
  $set: {
    "customerAccount.payStatus": "New Value"
  }
})
```